# On iOS, how can I apply a set of common styles to UILabels without having to subclass for every last style?

Tags: ios, styles, uilabel

My app has several UILabels across it. There are several different styles that get re-used across the entire app, in different situations (different font sizes, different font colors, italic, etc). Is there a sane way to set global styles, without having several subclasses of UILabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about taking cue from UITableViewCell. Create an enumerated type for all your styles and have one class that handles all the setup for the different style. Something like

```
MyStyledLabel* label = [[MyStyledLabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:MyStyledLabelDefaultStyle];
```

If you want to get clever, you can use bit fields to combine in different ways.

```
MyStyledLabel* label = [[MyStyledLabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:MyStyledLabelRedColor|MyStyledLabelBoldText];
```

Hope that give you some ideas.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing. In my init method, I've got a big switch statement which goes through the different available styles, and sets the underlying UILabel's attributes accordingly.